# How to use typescript protobuf generated files in a gRPC angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js, grpc-web

### Summarize the problem

I'm learning how to use gRPC, and wanted to try to do a client-server connection. The server (in Elixir) works, though I had a few problems. But as I am mainly a back end developer, I have way more troubles with implementing it in Angular, and would appreciate to have some help.

I am using *Angular 8.2.9*, *Angular CLI 8.3.8* and *Node 10.16.0* for this project.

### What have I already done?

1. Created a new angular cli project with `ng new test-grpc`
2. Generated a module and a component with `ng g...`, and modify the base routing to have working pages and urls.
3. Installed Protobuf and gRPC libraries `npm install @improbable-eng/grpc-web @types/google-protobuf google-protobuf grpc-web-client protoc ts-protoc-gen --save`
4. Tooked the `.proto` file from my Elixir code and copied it in a folder `src/proto`
5. Added a `protoc`command in the package.json `scripts` : 
   `"protoc": "protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts.cmd --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:src/app/proto-gen --ts_out=service=true:src/app/proto-ts -I ./src/proto/ ./src/proto/*.proto"`
6. Called the command to generate the js and ts files  found in `src/app/proto-ts` and `src/app/proto-js`
7. Replaced any `_` with `-` in the names of the generated files.
8. Then I tried to add the following code in a ngOnInit: https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/tree/master/client/grpc-web#usage-overview such as:

```js
const getBookRequest = new GetBookRequest();
getBookRequest.setIsbn(60929871);
grpc.unary(BookService.GetBook, {
  request: getBookRequest,
  host: host,
  onEnd: res => {
    const { status, statusMessage, headers, message, trailers } = res;
    if (status === grpc.Code.OK && message) {
      console.log("all ok. got book: ", message.toObject());
    }
  }
});
```

I tried:

- To create the Request in the constructor arguments.
- To find how to add typescript files (I only find ways to add javascript files in a angular project, and the generated javascript are way heavier than the typescript, and don't have any explanation).
- To understand what the jspb.Message is (I still don't, but I think it is linked to this file: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/js/message.js)
- Tried to find a tutorial on how to implement rGPD in an angular app (404 none found)

### The .proto file, the two typescript generated files and the component trying to use them

The .proto file ():

```cpp
// src/proto/user.proto
syntax = "proto3";

service UserService {
  rpc ListUsers (ListUsersRequest) returns (ListUsersReply);
}

message ListUsersRequest {
  string message = 1;
}


message ListUsersReply {
  repeated User users = 1;
}

message User {
  int32 id = 1;
  string firstname = 2;
}
```

The typescript generated code (2 files):

```js
// src/app/proto-ts/user-pb.d.ts

import * as jspb from "google-protobuf";

export class ListUsersRequest extends jspb.Message {
  getMessage(): string;
  setMessage(value: string): void;

  serializeBinary(): Uint8Array;
  toObject(includeInstance?: boolean): ListUsersRequest.AsObject;
  static toObject(includeInstance: boolean, msg: ListUsersRequest): ListUsersRequest.AsObject;
  static extensions: {[key: number]: jspb.ExtensionFieldInfo<jspb.Message>};
  static extensionsBinary: {[key: number]: jspb.ExtensionFieldBinaryInfo<jspb.Message>};
  static serializeBinaryToWriter(message: ListUsersRequest, writer: jspb.BinaryWriter): void;
  static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): ListUsersRequest;
  static deserializeBinaryFromReader(message: ListUsersRequest, reader: jspb.BinaryReader): ListUsersRequest;
}

export namespace ListUsersRequest {
  export type AsObject = {
    message: string,
  }
}

export class ListUsersReply extends jspb.Message {
  clearUsersList(): void;
  getUsersList(): Array<User>;
  setUsersList(value: Array<User>): void;
  addUsers(value?: User, index?: number): User;

  serializeBinary(): Uint8Array;
  toObject(includeInstance?: boolean): ListUsersReply.AsObject;
  static toObject(includeInstance: boolean, msg: ListUsersReply): ListUsersReply.AsObject;
  static extensions: {[key: number]: jspb.ExtensionFieldInfo<jspb.Message>};
  static extensionsBinary: {[key: number]: jspb.ExtensionFieldBinaryInfo<jspb.Message>};
  static serializeBinaryToWriter(message: ListUsersReply, writer: jspb.BinaryWriter): void;
  static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): ListUsersReply;
  static deserializeBinaryFromReader(message: ListUsersReply, reader: jspb.BinaryReader): ListUsersReply;
}

export namespace ListUsersReply {
  export type AsObject = {
    usersList: Array<User.AsObject>,
  }
}

export namespace User {
  export type AsObject = {
    id: number,
    firstname: string,
  }
}
```

```js
// src/app/proto-ts/user-pb-service.d.ts
import * as user_pb from "./user-pb";
import {grpc} from "@improbable-eng/grpc-web";

type UserServiceListUsers = {
  readonly methodName: string;
  readonly service: typeof UserService;
  readonly requestStream: false;
  readonly responseStream: false;
  readonly requestType: typeof user_pb.ListUsersRequest;
  readonly responseType: typeof user_pb.ListUsersReply;
};

export class UserService {
  static readonly serviceName: string;
  static readonly ListUsers: UserServiceListUsers;
}

export type ServiceError = { message: string, code: number; metadata: grpc.Metadata }
export type Status = { details: string, code: number; metadata: grpc.Metadata }
interface UnaryResponse {
  cancel(): void;
}
interface ResponseStream<T> {
  cancel(): void;
  on(type: 'data', handler: (message: T) => void): ResponseStream<T>;
  on(type: 'end', handler: (status?: Status) => void): ResponseStream<T>;
  on(type: 'status', handler: (status: Status) => void): ResponseStream<T>;
}
interface RequestStream<T> {
  write(message: T): RequestStream<T>;
  end(): void;
  cancel(): void;
  on(type: 'end', handler: (status?: Status) => void): RequestStream<T>;
  on(type: 'status', handler: (status: Status) => void): RequestStream<T>;
}
interface BidirectionalStream<ReqT, ResT> {
  write(message: ReqT): BidirectionalStream<ReqT, ResT>;
  end(): void;
  cancel(): void;
  on(type: 'data', handler: (message: ResT) => void): BidirectionalStream<ReqT, ResT>;
  on(type: 'end', handler: (status?: Status) => void): BidirectionalStream<ReqT, ResT>;
  on(type: 'status', handler: (status: Status) => void): BidirectionalStream<ReqT, ResT>;
}

export class UserServiceClient {
  readonly serviceHost: string;

  constructor(serviceHost: string, options?: grpc.RpcOptions);
  listUsers(
    requestMessage: user_pb.ListUsersRequest,
    metadata: grpc.Metadata,
    callback: (error: ServiceError|null, responseMessage: user_pb.ListUsersReply|null) => void
  ): UnaryResponse;
  listUsers(
    requestMessage: user_pb.ListUsersRequest,
    callback: (error: ServiceError|null, responseMessage: user_pb.ListUsersReply|null) => void
  ): UnaryResponse;
}
```

The attempt to use them in a component file:

```js
// src/app/modules/user/pages/list/list.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { grpc } from "@improbable-eng/grpc-web";

import { UserService } from '../../../../proto-ts/user-pb-service.d'
import { ListUsersRequest } from '../../../../proto-ts/user-pb.d'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const listUsersRequest = new ListUsersRequest();
    listUsersRequest.setMessage("Hello world");

    grpc.unary(UserService.ListUsers, {
      request: listUsersRequest,
      host: "0.0.0.0:50051",
      onEnd: res => {
        const { status, statusMessage, headers, message, trailers } = res;
        if (status === grpc.Code.OK && message) {
          console.log("all ok. got the user list: ", message.toObject());
        } else {
          console.log("error");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

### Expected result and actual results

**I expect to be able to use non angular typescript code in a component (or a service).**
**As the code above (but the component file) is generated, it shouldn't be modified**, because any changes on the `.proto` file will overwrite any modification done in these two generated files.

For now, I am blocked by these two error message, which appear depending of which file I saved last: `TypeError: _proto_ts_user_pb_d__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.ListUsersRequest is not a constructor` (if I save a protobuf generated file last, no error in the console) or `src\app\proto-ts\user-pb-service.d.ts and src\app\proto-ts\user-pb.d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.`(if I saved a angular file last, same error message in the console).

Adding the 'files' or 'include' in the `tsconfig.json` (which is the generated by angular CLI without any modifications) create another error: `Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Comment: you should probably show tsconfig.json as well and also show the error messages in a more specific way: what class is reported as not a constructor? What file_name.ts is missing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated the error messages. The tsconfig.json is the one generated by the CLI without any modification (I removed the few lines I added when I saw the new error).

Comment: TypeScript support for grpc-web in pretty experimental right now. There isn't official TypeScript support for protobuf to start with. You can check out https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/pull/626 for now. Someone had tried to get grpc-web to work in an Angular app.

Comment: I tried to reproduce on a new angular app, and everythin worked fine. Didn't have time to investigate why it acted this way though.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this question is old and you have kind of solved the problem already.

But I would like to add two points:

1. The grpc-web stack is overly complicated. The protobuf JavaScript API is sparsely documented, grpc-web is no better, and generating TypeScript declarations on top only makes matters worse.
2. There are alternatives to the official stack! [ts-proto](https://github.com/stephenh/ts-proto) for example generates pure TypeScript.

I was having very similar experiences with grpc web and Angular and started [protobuf-ts](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts) out of frustration. It is a protoc-plugin that generates TypeScript and supports grpc-web. It is written from scratch and might be a viable alternative...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to do it. More of a work around (if your project is not big already big).

I came back recently to this problematic. Didn't want to try new things, so I just created a new angular project following these steps:

1. Put gRPC first
2. Check if everything worked
3. Add a module from the initial project
4. Repeat 2 and 3 until there is no more module to add

Now it works for me.

As I say, it isn't the best solution as the initial problem remains in the initial project. But this is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**Error here:**

```
import { UserService } from '../../../../proto-ts/user-pb-service.d'
import { ListUsersRequest } from '../../../../proto-ts/user-pb.d'
```

**correct import:** (remove ".d" at the end of Module name)

Note that *.js and *.d.ts must be the same folder.

```
import { UserService } from '../../../../proto-ts/user-pb-service'
import { ListUsersRequest } from '../../../../proto-ts/user-pb'
```

**package.json:** option compile ts_out=service=grpc-web:

```
  "scripts": {
    "grpc:all": "protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=node_modules\\.bin\\protoc-gen-ts.cmd --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./src/app/proto/generated --ts_out=service=grpc-web:./src/app/proto/generated -I ./src/app/proto ./src/app/proto/*.proto"
  },
```

The above compile option is for grpc with lib "@improbable-eng/grpc-web"
see the guide: [ts-protoc-gen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-protoc-gen)

**Your code should be like:**

```
// src/app/modules/user/pages/list/list.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { grpc } from "@improbable-eng/grpc-web";

import { UserService } from '../../../../proto-ts/user-pb-service'
import { ListUsersRequest } from '../../../../proto-ts/user-pb'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // build ProtoBuf Message to send
    const listUsersRequest = new ListUsersRequest();
    listUsersRequest.setMessage("Hello world");

    // ClientName = ServiceName + "Client"
    const service = new UserServiceClient('http://localhost:8080');
    
    // build headers of httpRequest
    // gRPC base on http2 protocol
    let metadata = new grpc.Metadata();

    metadata.set('header1', 'headerValue1');
    metadata.set('header2', 'headerValue2');

    // call gRPC service method
    service.ListUsers(listUsersRequest , metadata, (error, reply) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return;
      }

      console.log(reply));
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ts-proto](https://github.com/stephenh/ts-proto) as @TimoStamm mentioned, but these two links can save you time in generating appropriate models from proto files:

https://docs.buf.build/tour/generate-code
https://docs.buf.build/generate/usage